# Laravel Passport Auth::attempt() always returns false after I installed default laravel authorization

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-passport

Auth::attempt() worked perfectly good but for some reason today it always returns false(I think it's because I installed laravel authorization using ui auth). How can I fix this problem? Same code works on hosting where I didn't call ui auth.

login controller

```
 public function login(Request $request)
    {
    $request->validate([
        'email' => 'required|string|email',
        'password' => 'required|string',
    ]);

    if (config('recaptcha.enabled') && !$this->checkRecaptcha($request['recaptchaToken'], $request->ip())) {
         return response()->json([
                'message' => 'Captcha error'
            ], 401);
    }
    $credentials = request(['email', 'password']);
    if(!Auth::attempt($credentials))
        return response()->json([
            'message' => 'Unauthorized'
        ], 401);
    $user = $request->user();
    $tokenResult = $user->createToken('Personal Access Token');
    $token = $tokenResult->token;
    if ($request->remember_me)
        $token->expires_at = Carbon::now()->addWeeks(1);
    $token->save();
    return (['redirect' => redirect()->intended('/')->getTargetUrl()]);
}
```

axios

```
login(recaptchaToken) {
          this.emailError = false;
        this.passwordError = false;
        let th = this;
        axios.post('api/auth/login', {
            email: this.email,
            password: this.password,
            recaptchaToken: recaptchaToken
        })
            .then((response) => {
                if (response.data.redirect) {
                    th.login_error = false;
                    location.href = response.data.redirect;
                }
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                th.login_error = true;
            });
    },
```

auth.php

```
'defaults' => [
    'guard' => 'web',
    'passwords' => 'users',
],

'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'passport',
        'provider' => 'users',
        'hash' => false,
    ],
],
```